# Vagrant Shell Executes Successfully as User but it doesn't 'stick'

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, npm, vagrant, nvm

This code seems to work fine on 'vagrant up', but when I 'vagrant ssh' into the vm I have to redo everything in the "#doesn't take" block, even though I saw the successful output while the scripts were being run.

In Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000, auto_correct: true
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/www", create: true, group: "vagrant", owner: "vagrant"

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant/rootScript.sh"
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "vagrant/userScript.sh" 
end
```

rootScript.sh:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make

sudo apt-get update
```

userScript.sh:

```
cd www           
touch test.txt    # this is successfully created in the correct folder

whoami            # 'vagrant'
echo "${PWD}"     # 'home/vagrant/www'

# # Installing nvm
wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh

# # This enables NVM without a logout/login
export NVM_DIR="/home/vagrant/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

# Install a node and alias
nvm install 0.10.33

# ************** doesn't take **************    
nvm use 0.10.33
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
npm install
bower install
# *******************************************

whoami                   # still 'vagrant'
echo "${PWD}"            # still 'home/vagrant/www'
```

Why do these commands need to be re-run in ssh?  And is there anything I can do to make them 'take' while running as a script?  Driving me nuts.  Thanks for the help.

---

UPDATE -- just discovered that the npm and bower commands DID take -- only command that does not seem to be working in the script is 'nvm use 0.10.33'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nvm use` only sets the node version for that shell session.

To make it work for any new shells you should instead use `nvm alias default 0.10.33`. This is mentioned briefly in the [nvm README](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage):

> To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell, use the
>   alias 'default':
>
> `nvm alias default stable`

This will only work on new shells though so if you want to perform any commands at the same time you will need to use `nvm use 0.10.33` as well.

In your case you probably just want to add the `nvm alias default 0.10.33` command right at the end of your node configuration in userScript.sh.

Comment: That worked!  Doesn't make sense in retrospect but I had assumed the docs meant 'default' for other users... Thanks so much for the very clear explanation!